# React - unexpected token, expected ;

Tags: reactjs

the error that is thrown out is: Unexpected token, expected; (9:16)
This points to the first line of the renderNumbers() function. What's wrong with my syntax? I'm a bit confused as to what needs to be changed here to make it work.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

renderNumbers() {
  return this.props.numbers.map(n =>
    <Text>{n}</Text>
  );
}


export default class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.appName}>
          Countly
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.tally}>
          Tally: {this.props.count}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.tally}>
          Numbers: {this.props.numbers}
        </Text>
        <View>
          {this.renderNumbers()}
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.increment} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            +
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.decrement} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            -
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.power} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            pow
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.zero} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            0
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Counter.propTypes = {
  count: PropTypes.number,
  numbers: PropTypes.func,
  increment: PropTypes.func,
  decrement: PropTypes.func,
  zero: PropTypes.func,
  power: PropTypes.func
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  appName: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  tally: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 25
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    width: 100,
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 20
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20
  }
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: CHECK YOUR FILE EXTENSION, SHOULD BE .tsx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shouldn't you use `function renderNumbers()`? It looks like `renderNumbers` is not a method of class `Counter` but an individual function in your code.

Btw, `renderNumbers` was defined twice, although it's legal and not the cause of the problem.

Edit:

If you want to declare `renderNumbers()` as a [**prototype method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods) of class `Counter`, define it inside of the class:

```
export default class Counter extends React.Component {

    renderNumbers() {
       ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Otherwise, use keyword `function` to define a [**function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_declaration_(function_statement)):

```
function renderNumbers() {
    ...
}
```

It's just the syntax of ES6.

Comment: Sorry about renderNumbers being twice. That's not the problem. Was supposed to remove it before posting it here.

Comment: @Wasteland just check my first sentence.

Comment: isn't the word 'function' used only for stateless components? When it's a class component, it's supposed to be nameOfFunction() {}. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you Philip Tzou, Your answer helped me.... I have one more doubt also this error also occurs variable declaration also if i defined it in inside the class else if i defined it in inside the render the error is not raised.

Comment: @praveenkumar: If you defined the function inside of `render()` then it was a closure function but not a prototype method. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 4):

The reason your component is experiencing this error is because of the following:
 1. If you define a function outside of an ES6 class you must use the `function` keyword. If you do this, though, the `this` reference will be undefined when you call that function.
 2. If you define a function inside of a React Component (which is just an ES6 class), you do not need the "function" keyword in front of the function definition.

Option 1:

```
function renderNumbers() {
    return <Text>...</Text>
}

class Counter extends React.component {
  render() {
   /* Render code... */
  }
}
```

Option 2:

```
class Counter extends React.component {
  renderNumbers() {
    return <Text>...</Text>
  }
  render() {
   /* Render code... */
  }
}
```

The reason you were getting the error you described is because the Javascript compiler thinks you are "calling" and not "defining" `renderNumbers()`. So...it gets to the `)` and expects either a newline or `;` but it sees a `{` and throws an error.

Don't forget to use the `this` keyword if you use Option 2 to call `renderNumbers()`

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like:

```
import partys from "../data/TimeLines2000.json";

const Timeline = () => {
  return (
    <div>     <-- you will get the error if you're missing a wrapper element
    {partys.map(party =>
          <>
          <div className='partyContainer'>
```

Answer (score 0):

if inside a function based component, you declare functions (before return), it is good if you use the function keyword (then it will not throw the ; required error)